# flutter :Failed assertion dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to create a row contain three dropdown button but this error i can't understand why it appear

> ```
> There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: jan. 
> Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
> 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 805 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
>               items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
>                 return item.value == value;
>               }).length == 1'
> ```

there is my initial values and the lists which i use in value of dropdown buttons

```
var selected="Arabic";
  var select="pyramid";
  var sel="jan";
  List<String> languageList = ['Arabic','English','French','Germen'];
  List<String> placeList = ['pyramid','park','zoo','garden'];
  List<String> dateList = ['jan','feb','march','april'];
```

and this is the row which i am trying to create

```
Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                       DropdownButton<String>(
                                              value: selected ,
                                              items: languageList.map((language){
                                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: language ,
                                                  child: Text(language),
                                                );
                                              }).toList(),
                                              onChanged: (vr){
                                                setState(() {
                                                  selected=vr;
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),

                                       DropdownButton<String>(
                                              value: select ,
                                              items: placeList.map((place){
                                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: place ,
                                                  child: Text(place),
                                                );
                                              }).toList(),
                                              onChanged: (ve){
                                                setState(() {
                                                  select=ve;
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),

                                       DropdownButton<String>(
                                              value: sel  ,
                                              items: languageList.map((dat){
                                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                  value: dat ,
                                                  child: Text(dat),
                                                );
                                              }).toList(),
                                              onChanged: (vm){
                                                setState(() {
                                                  sel=vm;
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
```

can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using Same Language list two times and giving selected object as date **"jan"** in value

Third dropDown input List is **languageList**, but your are giving selected item as "Jan" which is not in the list.. change the input list as **dateList**

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
       DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selected ,
              items: languageList.map((language){
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: language ,
                  child: Text(language),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (vr){
                setState(() {
                  selected=vr;
                });
              },
            ),

       DropdownButton<String>(
              value: select ,
              items: placeList.map((place){
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: place ,
                  child: Text(place),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (ve){
                setState(() {
                  select=ve;
                });
              },
            ),

       DropdownButton<String>(
              value: sel  ,
              items: dateList.map((dat){ //changes need to done
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: dat ,
                  child: Text(dat),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (vm){
                setState(() {
                  sel=vm;
                });
              },
            ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: also add  isExpanded: true,  isDense: true, inside dropown when u using inside Row